# Can't find imported enum from a Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, enums, pom.xml

Please bear with me. I am quite new to Maven and tried many solutions I gathered here but to no avail, unsuccessful.

I have previous enum called `DialogResponse` in my project, together with other classes that make up a simple dialog functionality in my JavaFX project. Recently I decided to recreate this feature into a separate library and published it in Maven Central.

I now deleted the previous enum and classes from my current project and applied the new dependency in my pom file:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.daytron</groupId>
      <artifactId>SimpleDialogFX</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

This works well in importing other enums and class, but somehow the new `DialogResponse` cannot be imported. It gives me cannot find symbol.

I tried using search Maven Repo feature in netbeans and it points me back to my library and if I click it nothing happens.

I also double check that enum class exist in my Dependency folder.

I tried `mvn -U clean install` but it didn't solve the problem.

I tried opening a new project and apply the dependency, but weirdly enough it does have the same problem.

I also tried reverting to v1.0.0 and works well on any project, but I need the latest version.

I tried typing the import code but resulted to cannot find symbol.

I also tried to use:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.daytron</groupId>
            <artifactId>SimpleDialogFX</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But it didn't solve it.

Last night, it was working well when I created a new project. But today when I tried to apply this to my JavaFX project, it seems Maven "forgot" about it.

Is this because Maven only remembers the previous enum? If so, how do I force Maven to now point to the new enum in the library. (I have deleted the original enum in the project). To make it clear, only this enum is in question, the rest of library enum and classes can be imported.

Here are more information:

- You check the library source code in here: https://github.com/Daytron/SimpleDialogFX
- Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)
- Java version: 1.8.0_20
- Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre
- Platform encoding: UTF-8
- OS name: "linux" version: "3.13.0-36-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solved it by editing the jar class in question (added few extra whitespaces) so it won't be the same with the similar deleted class in the main program.

I saved the edited library jar and recompiled it (not the jar but the program that depends on the api. I also restarted the machine. This difference, finally recognize the class in library.